# Is it possible to embed a part of a web site into my web site?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I wish to 'steal' a div of a web site and embed it on my site (without using iframe). Can anyone tell me what is the exact way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Is the site on the same domain?

Comment: I mean site on the different domain.

Comment: You'll have to use serverside technology, as JavaScript can't send requests across domains. Google **XSS**.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Simple:

You can use file_get_contents() or http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm  to get the page as all the HTML and then get the DIV using javascript or Jquery.

An example would be:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.somesite.com/');
```

Then you can parse the $homepage variable.

OR

What I would do is:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
$ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to [@jini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761658/is-it-possible-to-embed-a-part-of-a-web-site-into-my-web-site/5761672#5761672), you could make that script into a file, `gate.php`, and load things using only jQuery:

```
$('#container').load('gateway.php?url=foo.com #target_div');
```

And a possible `gateway.php`:

```
<?php    
print file_get_contents($_GET['url']);    
?>
```

Just make sure to sanitize your input!

Answer (score 0):

you can use yahoo yql with data scraping, exactly made for these purpose.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-code-examples.html#yql_html_scraper

you can use Xpath

ex

```
select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s={ticker_sym}" and xpath='//div[@id="yfi_headlines"]/div[2]/ul/li/a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo pipes is a good place to start using the 'fetch page' module. After that it'a a case of rubbing or changing out the html that you don't want with the regex module.

Embedding can be done in two ways:

1. using the pipes callback feature to run javascript inside the page that swaps the part of the pages static / original content to that provided by the pipe.

2.Yahoo pipes have a module that will POST data (in JSON format) to a suitable input processing page that will store the information for inclusion in any page that requires the data.

A brilliant (and wholly legal) example of this action can be seen over at http://bishop.comxa.com

Ask nicely they may even give you some pointers.